# How to include spaces between equal sign when working with ini files c#?

Tags: c#, ini

Hi I have an ini file that's formatted like this

```
[Text]
abcd = 1234
text = 1002
some = 4414
last = 1824
```

However when I use the inifile class, a class I found online for dealing with ini files:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

// Change this to match your program's normal namespace
namespace Program
{
    class IniFile   // revision 10
    {
        string Path;
        string EXE = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;

        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        static extern long WritePrivateProfileString(string Section, string Key, string Value, string FilePath);

        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string Section, string Key, string Default, StringBuilder RetVal, int Size, string FilePath);

        public IniFile(string IniPath = null)
        {
            Path = new FileInfo(IniPath ?? EXE + ".ini").FullName.ToString();
        }

        public string Read(string Key, string Section = null)
        {
            var RetVal = new StringBuilder(255);
            GetPrivateProfileString(Section ?? EXE, Key, "", RetVal, 255, Path);
            return RetVal.ToString();
        }

        public void Write(string Key, string Value, string Section = null)
        {
            WritePrivateProfileString(Section ?? EXE, Key, Value, Path);
        }

        public void DeleteKey(string Key, string Section = null)
        {
            Write(Key, null, Section ?? EXE);
        }

        public void DeleteSection(string Section = null)
        {
            Write(null, null, Section ?? EXE);
        }

        public bool KeyExists(string Key, string Section = null)
        {
            return Read(Key, Section).Length > 0;
        }
    }
}
```

It is able to add to the ini file however it is in a format like such:

```
test=0010
```

The read function also does not work except on the ones that the write function created.

How would I be able to change the code so that it places spaces before and after the equal sign? Adding a space before the value works but having one after the key does not. Also I'm hesitant to add spaces in the value because I'm afraid it might alter the actual value and make in in readable for the operation I'm using it for.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Any `.ini` files I have worked with all have no spaces between the key, =, and value. I think this is pretty standard. Is there a reason why you want to do this, other than readability?

Comment: If your 'ini-file' is written in a non-standard format you should correct it. Or you can write your own ini-class..

Comment: ini files are not properties files. If you want k = v so you have to trim() them and accept that no key or value of yours contains spaces at start and end of string. If you want custome ini file, pm me and I will give you source code of my ini class, maybe 12 hours later

Comment: Also I received the task for this INI file I didn't create it. I'm not sure how to private message here but if you could it would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another IniFile class that will enable you to achieve that spacing: https://github.com/MarioZ/MadMilkman.Ini

What you need to do is provide an IniOptions with the required formatting, like this:

```
IniOptions options = new IniOptions();
options.KeySpaceAroundDelimiter = true;

IniFile ini = new IniFile(options);
ini.Load("path to your input INI file");

// Do something with file's sections and their keys ...

ini.Save("path to your output INI file");
```